# Modify theme component asha 1.0

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia, lwuit-resource-editor

Is there a way of modifying the default asha 1.0 theme for a lwuit app, I have tried altering title area for a form in my app using the following code:

```
getTitleArea().getStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
getTitleArea().setVisible(false);
getTitleComponent().setVisible(false);
```

however it does nothing, this code worked other applications that did not target asha 1.0 platform. Is there a different way of modifying this. Have tried using lwuit resource editor as well,can change different components such as button,form background and others but still it does not change title or softbutton commands which is what I want to change.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said in others questions, the native header in Nokia SDK is not editable. This methods that you are using are invalid to modify the style of the header, the Nokia SDK don't get access to do that. And if you want to follow the Nokia guidelines in your app, you should keep it as the SDK gives to you.

Instead, if you still want to change this header, you can try to set your app in fullscreen and build a custom header on your own. Be careful, if you do that, you will lose the native navigation. If you want more info, take a look here in Stackoverflow, there are so many questions talking about that. In the Nokia developer forum, you can find many posts talking about that.

Comment: thanks had not seen those questions, but need to change the header coz its an image application and the header combined with the command take up too much space and as such compress the images

Comment: So, do what I've said. Use the fullscreen mode and create your own header if you want or not. Please if the answer was useful accept it and upvote.

Comment: I am new don't have rep to upvote yet...however is it still possible to set full screen mode if I am using a form and not canvas

Comment: Yes, it is possible, using Display.getInstance().setForceFullScreen(true);